# amCharts 4 - valueAxis Tooltip Precision Too Low

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

See [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yrKJNd).  The valueAxis has a maxPrecision of 8 and number formatting to allow 8 significant digits:

```
valueAxis.maxPrecision = 8;
valueAxis.numberFormatter = new am4core.NumberFormatter();
valueAxis.numberFormatter.numberFormat = '0.00000000';
```

However, the valueAxis tooltip only seems to show 4 significant digits.  The data has 6.

How can I set the valueAxis tooltip to have a precision of at least 6?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
valueAxis.extraTooltipPrecision = 2;
```

to add two significant digits.